# storing original index in an array

Tags: c, arrays, merge

I am trying to perform a mergesort without actually rearranging the array.  Let me explain a little better.  Say I have an array:

```
3
5
6
7
0
4
1
2
```

If 5 (currently at index 1) gets moved to index 6 for example I need my program to remember the index of where 5 was originally stored.  How can I remember the original index?

Comment: Is there a question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: In that case you take a copy of array and sort it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a parallel array of pointers to the original array. Sort the pointers, not the originals. Your index positions remain unchanged, and you now have a sorted "view" of the array.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use a structure for every element, and make an array of those structure objects. For example-

```
typedef struct
{
  int val;
  int index;
}element;
```

Loop through the array, fill the *val* field with the value and the other with the original position.

When sorting, you compare on the *val* field, and leave the *index* intact. So now you have the original position, and the array can also be sorted.